# How to load from database with condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to programming and I have my hands on a web app from a company and tried to mess around and do some changes. The app was built with **PHP**, **MySQL**, and **CodeIgniter**, as I was told, and it's used from the company to manage orders.

When a user wants to see the orders he clicks on the specified button and the app loads all the orders from the database, but because there are more than 10.000 orders it's slow at load. So, I want to add an option where the first load happens to get only the orders of **the last 6 months** and if the user wants to view older orders then I should add a button or something similar and load the rest.

```php
<?php
 $count=1;
 $this->db->order_by("order_number", "desc");
 $completed_orders=$this->db->get_where('orders' , array(
                                        'order_status' => 'completed',
                                        'category' => 'mesoportes'
                                        ))->result_array();
 foreach ($completed_orders as $row):
?>
```

Any idea how i may do that.

Comment: if you want to get the last 6 months, you'll have to have had a db field that stored some sort of timestamp for when the order was created. otherwise, you'll have to just load the latest orders up to a certain amount using a `limit` statement. that being said, I doubt a user would read through more than 100 of the most recent orders, so I would recommend either using pagination or an ajax-type solution like datatables. either way, your going to have to try something and not rely on stack as a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I think the limit() function should work for you. [here ist a link](https://www.bladephp.co/limit-query-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

You can initially load a certain amount of orders for eg. 10, and generate an AJAX call on the click of a button to load another 10 orders and so on.

The method to load orders from the database can be -

```
function get_orders($start, $limit){
 return $this->db->select('*')->where(array('order_status' => 'completed','category' => 'mesoportes'))->limit($limit, $start)->order_by("order_number", "desc")->get('orders')->result_array();
}
```

Each time increase a count variable by 10 and pass it to this function.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve is the perfect definition to apply pagination. Pagination will help your app split the database data into individual pages, which is an efficient method of showing a large number of records in a small space. However, you want to apply a huge chuck data query. Six months is a long time and you can get many orders in that period.

#### What can I do?

First, I will try to solve it using your original idea. To that end, you just need to create a new `get_completed_orders()` function that receives two parameters `$start_date`, and  `$end_date`. There parameters should be added to the `get_where`. I guessing the name of your date is `order_datetime` and compare it with the previous parameters.

```php
$start_date = '2018-11-01';
$end_date = '2019-05-31';
$completed_orders = get_completed_orders($start_date, $end_date);

function get_completed_orders($start_date, $end_date){
    return $this->db->get_where(
        'orders',
        array(
            'order_status' => 'completed',
            'category' => 'mesoportes',
            'order_datetime >=' => $start_date,
            'order_datetime <' => $end_date
        )
    )->order_by('order_number', 'desc')->result_array();
}
```

That approach will bring all the completed orders between the two dates. Yeah, but that is still not effective for a mobile application or a web application. Specially for a user interface. **Then, how can I make it more efficient?** Well, if you open your gmail, you will get the last 20 emails, and the using pagination will you move back and forwards according your needs. They don't show you thousandth of emails from the last six months, right? So, if we follow that idea we can all add a `$limit`, and `$offset` to the `get_completed_orders()` to create a pagination like approach.

```php
$start_date = '2018-11-01';
$end_date = '2019-05-31';
$limit = 20; // max number of orders
$offset = $prev_offset + $limit; // where is gonna to start
$completed_orders = get_completed_orders($start_date, $end_date, $limit, $offset);
$prev_offset = $offset; 


// Function implementation
function get_completed_orders($start_date, $end_date, $limit, $offset) {
    return $this->db->get_where(
        'orders',
        array(
            'order_status' => 'completed',
            'category' => 'mesoportes',
            'order_datetime >=' => $start_date,
            'order_datetime <' => $end_date
        ), 
        $limit,
        $offset
    )->order_by('order_number', 'desc')->result_array();
}
```

Now, your interface will receive only 20 completed orders for each page. So you need to modify your interface to support this new feature.